# Connect Visual Studio Online with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I've done the following so far:

1. Created an Azure Active Directory instance
2. Created a Visual Studio Online instance

I am attempting to "connect" the VSO instance to the AAD instance, but in the "Connect a directory" dialog all I see is "none" and "default directory", the AAD I created in step 1 does not appear on the list. Am I missing some critical step here?

This is what I see when I go to Visual Studio Online -> select my instance -> Configure -> Connect

[image: AAD-VSO screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the experience you're looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the reason you’re not seeing it in the drop down is that it isn’t the directory associated with your subscription. You can change that via settings. In the settings for your subscription, click on 'Edit directory'

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's the conclusion I came to based on information from another forum as well. Seems counter-intuitive though. Why does it have to be the "primary" subscription AAD only? Why can't I create an "independent" directory and use it for VSO?